# Milliseconds using square wave RTC

Tags: rtc, millis

i am trying to make a code that prints the time hh:mm:ss:ms using RTC,i have made it using millis() but it  is not accurate +/-2 milliseconds

ho can i make it using sq wave and intterupt

here is the code that i have used

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 RTC;      // This is the DS1307 hardware RTC
RTC_Millis SoftRTC;   // This is the millis()-based software RTC
long startMS;  // This will hold the start time in milliseconds

void setup ()
{
    Wire.begin();
    RTC.begin();                       // Connect to the DS1307
    SoftRTC.begin(RTC.now());  // Initialize SoftRTC to the current time
    startMS = millis();  // get the current millisecond count
}

void loop()
{
    DateTime now = SoftRTC.now();
    long nowMS = millis();
   
    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print((nowMS - startMS)%1000, DEC);  // print milliseconds
    Serial.println();
```

i tried to put this code that is based on ISR but with no luck

```
volatile time_t isrUTC;         // ISR's copy of current time in UTC
volatile time_t millisecondsFromISR;         // ISR's copy of current time millisecond offset

void incrementTime()
{
    millisecondsFromISR = millis();  //do first to get most accuracy
    ++isrUTC;
}

int getMilliseconds() {
    // need to make an atomic copy:
    nointerrupts();
    unsigned long t = millisecondsFromISR;
    interrupts();

    return millis() - t;
}
```

Comment: what is not accurate +/-2 milliseconds? ... the `prints the time hh:mm:ss:ms` takes time to execute

Comment: so if i make it with external clock will it make a diff?

Comment: You cannot get better than ±2 ms with `millis()`. If you need more accuracy, use `micros()`.

Comment: same code 
or what do u suggest?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is record the number of milliseconds at the moment the square wave toggles on its 1 second cycle. Then your milliseconds is the difference between that and the current.

In short: update `startMS` when triggered by the RTC's output.

Comment: do u have a helping code?

Comment: @AmrAhmed no, but you already have code to set startms in your program, and there are plenty of interrupt examples on the web.

Comment: yes i have checked these codes for interrupt with no luck  to make a running code

Comment: @AmrAhmed Then maybe you should try again, and then show us what you tried, and we may be able to help you with it.

Comment: volatile time_t isrUTC;         // ISR's copy of current time in UTC
volatile time_t millisecondsFromISR;         // ISR's copy of current time millisecond offset
...
void incrementTime()
{
    millisecondsFromISR = millis();  //do first to get most accuracy
    ++isrUTC;
}
...
int getMilliseconds() {
    // need to make an atomic copy:
    nointerrupts();
    unsigned long t = millisecondsFromISR;
    interrupts();

    return millis() - t;
}

this one of the codes that i tried to work on with no luck

Comment: @AmrAhmed Comments are not for code.

Comment: i have added the code in my question

Comment: And what didn't work with it? How is that code snippet integrated with the rest of your code?

Comment: i could not make it working

Comment: Without seeing how that snippet is integrated with the rest of your code, or how the RTC module is wired up, we cannot help/.

Comment: unfortunately this what i got when i tried to integrate both